# 3-Monitor/3 Comptuter Complex Setup Help

Tags: hdmi, displays, switch, display-port, usb-c

I'm trying to optimize my hardware setup in my home office, and I'd really like to have something like this setup: [image: Computer Setup]
I'm not sure how to accomplish this, if it's even possible. All of the arrows show video being sent- this is purely for video (I have the keyboard/mouse situation set up already).

What hardware would I be able to use for the 2 switches (or 1 switch to combine the 2 that I have in the diagram)?

Comment: Do all of your computers have Thunderbolt 3 or 4?

Comment: Needs a lot more detail for this be answerable. 1) hosts PC/Mac, CPU/GPU 2) monitor frequencies

Answer (score 1):

If you search for "KVM Switch" on Amazon, that will get you part of the way to your end goal. The one I use only allows 2 input computers to go to 2 monitors. For some reason they do not sell these at stores like Best Buy and MicroCenter so results may not be perfect depending on you Hardware/Operating System set up.

Comment: He may need to feed one KVM switch into another, but this should work fairly well.